# Georeference 3857 TIF to 3857

Tags: qgis

I have a poorly georeferenced raster in EPSG:3857 and when I want to georeference it again to 3857, the position is completely outside the territory. The coordinates of a correctly georeferenced tif should be approx. 2174018, 6199663. But the resulting georeferenced TIF has coordinates around 0, 0. I have QGIS 3.26.3. Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Where did you get this GeoTiff? What have you tried to correct it? Can you post a link to your GeoTiff?

Comment: In the past I georeferenced a tiff (without coordinates) to 3857 by parcel. It was not well georeferenced, but now I no longer have a tiff without coordinates. I only have a georeferenced tiff. And I opened this georeferenced tiff in Georeferencer and wanted to georeference it again.

Comment: Sounds like you georefenced the tif to 4326, but set the CRS to 3857. Try setting the CRS to 4326.

Comment: What exactly should I set to 4326? I tried to export the tiff to 4326 and then georeference it to 3857, but the resulting tiff is not displayed.

Comment: Web Mercator is such an awful projection, with Y values expanding toward infinity at the poles, that any interpolation from an incorrect location will be hopless (fitting a line to an exponential curve). You probably need to start over, possibly with new data. If you have 3857 data near the origin, it is likely not 3857 at all, and you are on Null Island.

Comment: In QGIS 2.18 this works. The georeferenced tif has the correct location. But if I open this tif in QGIS 3.26, I have to set it to 3857 so that it is positioned correctly. Maybe a bug in version 3.26?